Fail to load library in KDB kernel jupyter notebook
I have installed the arrowkdb library, and use it to load parquet files in KDB. My $QHOME directory now contains:
├── kc.lic
├── arrowkdb.q 
├── l64
│   ├──arrowkdb.so
│   └── q
└── q.k

But when use \l to load arrowkdb.q, it raised following errors:
evaluation error:

libarrow.so.900: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

  [3]  /home/jiahe/q/arrowkdb.q:5: dt.na:`arrowkdb 2:(`null;1);
                                                   ^

  [0]  \l arrowkdb.q
       ^

So far checked:

The module works well when start from console:

~/q$ q arrowkdb.q 
KDB+ 4.1 2024.07.08 Copyright (C) 1993-2024 Kx Systems
l64/ 16(24)core 579514MB xxxx ubuntu-xxxxx-amd64-base xx.xx.xx.xx EXPIRE 2025.06.15 xxxxxxx@gmail.com KDB PLUS TRIAL #5020784

q)show t: .arrowkdb.fd.field[`int_field;.arrowkdb.dt.int64[]]
1i
q)


I can load other q-scripts in $QHOME with \l in the notebook:
notebook interface

I am new to KDB and also know little about Apache Arrow. Thank you very much for any suggestions:)
EDIT: I have tested several more times and find following patterns:

In my kdb conda environment, where I installed required packages to run KDB notebook, \l arrowkdb.q will raise the same error in q console as in the notebook.
While in base environment, \l arrowkdb.q works normally.
Is there anyway to test whether the problem is caused by anaconda environment?


make sure the directory is on the exported environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH

@ticktalk I have added export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/myname/q/l64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to my .bashrc file, but still has the same problem.

Compare getenv`LD_LIBRARY_PATH in q and in Jupyter.

Both of them return the path "/home/myname/q/l64:"; I also tried setenv, which doesn't help either:(

It is a dynamic load function "2:" https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dynamic-load/.
So it will look for libraries in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH if you use Linux. Please note the error you posted says that you don't have libarrow.so library, not arrowkdb.so You need to put all missed *.so libraries (correctly built for your platform) to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it will work.
arrowkdb "Third-party library installation" is here https://github.com/KxSystems/arrowkdb/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#third-party-library-installation

Hi Alex, I think your point is right. Alternatively, I copy my arrowkdb file to the ~/.conda/kx/q directory and solved the issue. Thanks!
